# How to do unit test for @ouput with test data, Angular 8?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to write jasmine unit for below **testComponent**. This is my very first try on writing unit test cases.

Here I'm trying to pass object via **click** event. but have little bit confusion in configuring test data with same structure in `spec.ts` file.

When hit ng test, im getting `position` of `undefined`

So far I've done like below

```
<button (click)="clickToCheck();"> </button>
```

**testComponent.ts**

```
export class testComponent implements  {

  @Output() passVal = new EventEmitter();
  @Input() checkEmployeePosition: any;

 clickToCheck() {
    const testData = {
      position: this.checkEmployeePosition.level
    };
    this.passVal.emit(testData);
  }
}
```

**testComponent.spec.ts**

```
import { DebugElement, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";
import {
  TestBed,
  ComponentFixture,
  fakeAsync,
  tick,
} from "@angular/core/testing";
import { By } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { testComponent } from "./testComponent.component";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url"

fdescribe("testComponent", () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<testComponent>;
  let component: testComponent;
  let de: DebugElement;
  let btn: ElementRef;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [testComponent],
    });
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(testComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    de = fixture.debugElement;
    btn = de.query(By.css("button"));
  });

  it("should create", () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  describe("passVal", () => {

    /*
    let testData = {
        name : 'hell0 world'
    }
    */
    it("should emit when the button is clicked", () => {
      spyOn(component.passVal, "emit");
      btn.nativeElement.click(); 
      expect(component.passVal.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);
    });
    it("should emit when clickToCheck() is called", () => {
      spyOn(component.passVal, "emit");
      component.emitContinue(); 
      expect(component.passVal.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1);
    });
    it("should emit when the button is clicked", () => {
      component.passVal.subscribe((next: any) => {
        expect(next).toEqual(1);
      });
      btn.nativeElement.click();
    });
  });
});
```

Please help me on this.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Your last test is the only one you need, but do not forget to initialize `checkEmployeePosition` and add done:

```js
    it("should emit when the button is clicked", done => {
      component.checkEmployeePosition = {level: 'dummy'};
      component.passVal.subscribe((next: any) => {
        expect(next).toEqual(1);
        done();
      });
      btn.nativeElement.click();
    });
```

Another way to test it is wrapping TestComponent inside a host component in order to give `Input() checkEmployeePosition` a value.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @htn .. this is my actual structure `const testData = {
      position: this.checkEmployeePosition.level
    };` but when i run test its show position undefined. do i need change my structure ?

Comment: Normally, with my code, `position` should be `dummy` string.

Answer (score 0):

```
it('should emit when the button is clicked', () => {
    let expected;

    component.checkEmployeePosition = {level: 'top'};
    fixture.detectChanges();

    component.passVal.subscribe(data => expected = data);

    btn.nativeElement.click();

    expect(expected).toEqual({ position: 'top' });
});
```

or

```
it('should emit when the button is clicked', () => {
    spyOn(component.passVal, 'emit');

    component.checkEmployeePosition = {level: 'top'};
    fixture.detectChanges();

    btn.nativeElement.click();

    expect(component.passVal.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ position: 'top' });
});
```

Comment: i'm getting `any
Property 'checkEmployeePosition' does not exist on type 'checkEmployeePosition'` even thought i imported it properly. if you not mind can pls share stackblitz for this

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-ghuuds
Take a look please. Pay attention on the `hello.component.spec.ts`. I did not change a default stackblitz structure.